# Why unity editor script Debug.Log doesn't show in console on startup

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use following code in Assets/Editor/TestEditorScript.cs

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class TestEditorScript
{
    static TestEditorScript()
    {
        Debug.Log("test editor script");
    }
}
```

when I start unity, the unity console is empty, why?

here is my [full code](https://github.com/roroco/unity-editor-script-cannot-debug-log), I only try official tutorial survival shooter

Comment: This should work. What happens if you type `Debug.Log("test editor script");` in a normal script then run play/run it? Does that show up?

Comment: @Programmer I hope when unity editor start, unity editor console show "test editor script" but it doesn't show

Comment: I know. Do what I said in my first comment.